# how to access dictionary in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I access the "x " and "y" at the same time for computing difference between successive terms from a list of dictionary with the following contents.

```
data_points = [{ "y": 621, "x": 399, "time ns": 107353592,
                 "time ms": 1529423113, "cameraID": 0 },
               { "y": 621, "x": 399, "time ns": 111057583,
                 "time ms": 1529423113, "cameraID": 0 },
               { "y": 621, "x": 399, "time ns": 114741998,
                 "time ms": 1529423113, "cameraID": 0 },
               { "y": 621, "x": 399, "time ns": 118388882,
                 "time ms": 1529423113, "cameraID": 0 }
              ]
```

I tried this and did not work

```
data_points[0]['x']['y']
```

Comment: data_points[0]['x']['y'] will return error because you're saying that there is another key inside x called y and you are trying to access that value which doesnot exist

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't access multiple dictionary keys at once with that kind of syntax, but you can do it easily with a list comprehension. For instance, to get `x` and `y` from the first dictionary of your list, you can do:

```
[data_points[0][i] for i in ['x', 'y']]
```

To get:

```
[399, 621]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = itemgetter('x', 'y')(data_points[0])

(399, 621)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
abs(data_points[0]['x']-data_points[0]['y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourVariable = data_points[0]["x"]
anotherVariable = data_points[0]["y"]
newList = "{str(yourVariable)} {str(anotherVariable)}".split(" ")
accessX = newList[0]
accessY = newList[1]
```

If you want to compare both:

```
if accessX and accessY == "something like this":
     #then do whatever you want
```

Now you can access both in a string, then just use the `split()` method and take whichever word u want.